# Metoer geolocation get city state and country name name

Tags: javascript, meteor, geolocation

I have a code which gets longitude and latitude, I am having some hard time understanding how to get a current geolocation and display it automatically. I would like to get **city, state country name**

below is the code

```
<head>
  <title>Geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="/">Geolocation</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="locationDemo">
    {{> location}}
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<template name="location">
  <div>
    Lat: {{lat}}
  </div>
  <div>
    Lon: {{lon}}
  </div>
</template>
```

javascript

```
    _lat = {
  current: 0,
  dep: new Deps.Dependency,
  get: function(){
    this.dep.depend();

    if(this.current === 0){
      getLocation();
    }

    return this.current;
  },
  set: function(value){
    this.current = value;
    this.dep.changed();
    Deps.flush();
    return this.current;
  }
};

_lon = {
  current: 0,
  dep: new Deps.Dependency,
  get: function(){
    this.dep.depend();

    if(this.current === 0){
      getLocation();
    }

    return this.current;
  },
  set: function(value){
    this.current = value;
    this.dep.changed();
    Deps.flush();
    return this.current;
  }
};

function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
  _lat.set(position.coords.latitude);
  _lon.set(position.coords.longitude);
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
      break;
  }
}

  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        Session.set('lat', position.coords.latitude);
        Session.set('lon', position.coords.longitude);
    });
}, 5000);

Template.location.helpers({

  lat: function() { return Session.get('lat'); },
  lon: function() { return Session.get('lon'); }
  });
```

**Code on meteorpad**

http://meteorpad.com/pad/oR9aL3E2TSYFjjHGH/Leaderboard

Comment: hmm It looks like you need to read meteor tutorial about reactivity because for this you don't need to use Deps (you usually don't ever unless you create your own package) here is nice link to learn about it: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/

Comment: Will do that but do you think I can get city state and country name from this code? M new to coding and I don't understand much of Google geo location